# How to not include the Pause duration in the FFMPEG recording timeline

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, screencasts, pause, timeline

I'm trying to **pause** a screencast made with `ffmpeg` under Linux, giving the command:

```
kill -s SIGSTOP <PID>
```

**resuming** then it with the command:

```
kill -s SIGCONT <PID>
```

to finally **interrupt** it with the command:

```
kill <PID>
```

but the resulting file keeps the duration of the *pause command* in the timeline. For a better explanation of the problem, I realized a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h3t05ML9mvyIw9xtEwNmThQI1kEDvH7I/view?usp=drivesdk): as you can see, there are 14 seconds in which the timeline is locked (from 29th to 43th second), the same duration of the command to pause the screencast (`kill -s SIGSTOP <PID>`).

Is there any way to not include it in the final video output? The unique one that I thought is to cut the final output, "labeling" the pause command in such a way to know where to cut...

Thank you

Comment: I'm unable to test at this time, but try fixing the timestamps: `-vf setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB` (that's an output option). Other stuff... You can use `kill -s SIGSTOP $(pgrep ffmpeg)` assuming you're running one `ffmpeg` process. As for your command: you don't need `-re`, `-movflags faststart`, `-profile:v`, `-level`, `-r`, `-an`. Replace `-s` with `-video_size`. Replace `-b:v 32M` with `-crf 0`.

Comment: Hello, @llogan, thanks for your reply. For now I'm launching the screencast with a script that stores the pid of the process, as you can see in the notification at the beginning of the video. For now I start and stop the process with different `files.desktop` linked to the scripts. I used the `ps ax | grep ffmpeg` command only for this demo to explain the problem. The setting for the `ffmpeg` command has been a long test to find a good compromise between quality, framerate, smooth mouse movement, synchronized voice and a not too big output... I will try your suggestions! Cheers

Comment: Did setpts help?